# python3 -m venv returned non-zero exit status of 1

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, unix, virtualenv

I'm on fedora 28 and I tried creating a virtual environment by typing

`python3 -m venv env`

but I got this error:

```
[user@fedora28 projects]$ python3 -m venv env
Error: Command '['/home/user/projects/env/bin/python3', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```